# How do I get the generators of a group formed by combining two groups with known generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

Consider two groups, $G$ and $H$, with generating sets $S$ and $T$, respectively.  (That is, $G=\langle S \rangle$ and $H=\langle T  \rangle$.)  Let us say that we can represent elements of both $G$ and $H$ as $n\times n$ matrices.  I now want to combine $G$ and $H$ into a new group, denoted $J$.  The way I combine the groups is just by multiplication, i.e. every element of $J$ can be written as a product of a finite number of elements of $G$ and $H$.

My question is, what is the set of generators of $J$?  Is it just $S\cup T$?  Do I need to consider products of elements of from $S$ and $T$?  Does the answer depend upon the internal structure of $G$ and $H$?

Now, suppose I further stipulate that $G$ is a Lie group, so $S$ is a finite set of infinitesimal generators (but $H$ is still a finite group).  How then could I deduce the generators of this new group $J$?

Apologies if this is question is either elementary or poorly posed.  I am not a mathematician by training, but am trying to learn what I can!  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you're talking about the [free product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product), $\langle X|R\rangle*\langle Y|S\rangle=\langle X\sqcup Y|R\sqcup S\rangle$. I am not sure the free product of Lie groups is still a Lie group. Also see [group presentation notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group).

Comment: The answer to the first question is *yes*, $S \cup T$ is a generating set.

Comment: @whacka, I think you're right; I think that I do want to consider the free product. However, there's one statement Wikipedia has which I don't get- "Unless one of the groups G and H is trivial, the free product is always infinite."  I must be missing somethings, as I don't see why this is true.  Imagine that $G$ and $H$ are the symmetric groups on $n$ and $m$ objects, respectively.  We can embed both $G$ and $H$ in the space of $\max(m,n)\times\max(m,n)$ matrices.  Then isn't their free product just $S_{\max(m,n)}$, which is manifestly not infinite?

Comment: @whacka, also regarding Lie groups, I think it's okay if the resulting group is not a Lie group, but I still want the generator and generator relations to hold.

Comment: No the free product of symmetric groups is not a symmetric group. If you're assuming $G$ and $H$ are matrix groups and talking about $\langle G,H\rangle\subset{\rm GL}(V)$, then that's *not* the free product (generally). In fact, that group depends on *how* you embed $G$ and $H$ in ${\rm GL}(V)$. But the claim still holds: for any group we have $\langle\langle S\rangle,\langle T\rangle\rangle=\langle S\cup T\rangle$.

Comment: @whacka- I think I understand. Suppose I use choose an embedding where, for example, the elements of $S_2$ are contained within the elements of $S_3$. Then $in this case$ the free product is just $S_3$ (as every element in the free product is a product of elements of $S_2$ and $S_3$, but every element of $S_2$, here, is an element of $S_3$). This need not always be true though (if we chose a different embedding).  To the larger point though, the statement that $\langle\langle S\rangle,\langle T\rangle\rangle= \langle S \cup T\rangle$ $always$ is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!